How to access a containerized(Docker) TcpListener in .NET 8?
So, I have this code right here; it starts a TcpListener in .NET and is exactly the same as the example in the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-8.0

public static void Main()
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    try
    {
        // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
        Int32 port = 6425;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.80.69.10");

        // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        // Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;

        // Enter the listening loop.
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
            using TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            data = null;

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
              

  // Translate data bytes to an ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                // Process the data sent by the client.
                data = data.ToUpper();

                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                // Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        server.Stop();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
}

When I execute it in Visual Studio, it works just fine, but when it is containerized with Docker, the TcpClient can no longer establish a connection. The code above runs without exceptions in the container, but a strange bug occurs: the Console.Write lines are not printed in the logs when running in the container. However, I am sure it is reaching and executing the code based on breakpoints.
The code for the TcpClient is again the exact same as the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-8.0

Did you expose/publish the port in Docker to allow incoming connections?

The localAddr for the TcpListener almost definitely needs to be 0.0.0.0.  If it's anything in the 127.0.0.0/8 CIDR block, the server won't be reachable from outside its own container.  Do you get some sort of error in the client?  How are you connecting the client to the server?

On a side note: why are you trying to reimplement a TCP server? WHy not use an existing protocol? There are so many pitfalls, some of which I can already see in your code: lack of message framing, use of ASCII instead of Unicode, lack of async, not handing off the client to carry on listening. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html

Shot in the dark, are you F5ing / Ctrl+F5ing a windows container from VS? If so, it's a known issue that your output doesn't show up in the logs due to the debugger being the entrypoint. Either way can you give more context on the container OS?
